# forward VK API python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Из документации ВК:

"Боты в беседах могут пересылать сообщения и отвечать на них. Для этого нужно передать JSON-объект в параметре forward при отправке сообщения, заполнив поле conversation_message_ids. Формат объекта можно найти на странице документации."

**Как правильно передавать JSON-объект?**

Я использую def

````
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0, "forward" :  })```
````

Answer (score 1):

Формат должен выглядеть **так**:

```
{'owner_id': владелец сообщения, 
 'peer_id': беседа, 
 'conversation_message_ids': кв_айди сообщения,
 'message_ids': айди сообщения,
 'is_reply': параметр}
```

Взято из **[докуметации ВКонтакте](http://vk.com/dev/messages.send)**